# Customising ASP.NET Dynamic Data Operations

Tags: .net, asp.net, dynamic-data

Where can I intercept reads and updates for scaffolded tables?  I need to make certain records or fields read only to certain people and or after a certain date?  I also have a Departments list, where clicking a department brings up a list of Categories for that department.  I need to block access to the Department list to normal users, and only bring up Categories for their department.  How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a Custom Page for Each Entity and listen to the LinqDataSource's Selecting Event and add parameters/filter results there.

You could also add Custom FieldTemplates for additional control at the individual field level.